# 3.12 install fails on Intel MacBook Pro

Tags: python, installation

Trying to install python 3.12.0 using pyenv install.  I have a couple older versions installed already.

The install fails while loading python part.

Note the errors in the *config.log file* **(note "-version" or "-V" are not valid gcc-13 options)**

some output from config.log:

```
> gcc version 13.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 
> configure:5079: $? = 0
> **configure:5068: /usr/local/bin/gcc-13 -V >&5
> gcc-13: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
> gcc-13: fatal error: no input files**
> compilation terminated.
> configure:5079: $? = 1
> **configure:5068: /usr/local/bin/gcc-13 -qversion >&5
> gcc-13: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
> gcc-13: fatal error: no input files**
> compilation terminated.
> configure:5079: $? = 1
> **configure:5068: /usr/local/bin/gcc-13 -version >&5
> gcc-13: error: unrecognized command-line option '-version'
> gcc-13: fatal error: no input files**
> compilation terminated.
> configure:5079: $? = 1
> configure:5099: checking whether the C compiler works
> configure:5121: /usr/local/bin/gcc-13  -I/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/readline/include -I/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -IShell level: 4
> /usr/local/include -L/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/readline/lib -L/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib  -LShell level: 4
> /usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,Shell level: 4
> /usr/local/lib conftest.c -LShell level: 4
> /usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,Shell level: 4
> /usr/local/lib >&5
> ld: warning: duplicate -rpath 'Shell' ignored
> ld: warning: search path '/Users/mattblake/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib' not found
> ld: warning: search path 'Shell' not found
> ld: warning: search path 'Shell' not found
> ld: multiple errors: file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=level: in 'level:'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=4 in '4'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=4 in '4'; file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/usr/local/lib in '/usr/local/lib'; file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/usr/local/include in '/usr/local/include'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=level: in 'level:'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=4 in '4'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=4 in '4'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=level: in 'level:'; file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/usr/local/lib in '/usr/local/lib'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=level: in 'level:'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=4 in '4'; file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/usr/local/lib in '/usr/local/lib'; file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=level: in 'level:'; file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/usr/local/lib in '/usr/local/lib'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> configure:5125: $? = 1
> configure:5165: result: no
> configure: failed program was:
> confdefs.h */
> | #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
> | #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
> | #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
> | #define _PYTHONFRAMEWORK ""
> end confdefs.h.  */
> 
> int
> main (void)
> | {
> 
> |   ;
> return 0;
> | }
> configure:5170: error: in `/var/folders/5g/c6hfdcxd7tzf4c7ck1fztm640000gn/T/python-build.20231005083309.2171/Python-3.12.0':
> configure:5172: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
...
```

pyenv install 3.12.0

Expected it to work.

```
> Last 10 log lines:
> checking macOS SDKROOT... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
> checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-13
> checking whether the C compiler works... no
> configure: error: in `/var/folders/5g/c6hfdcxd7tzf4c7ck1fztm640000gn/T/python-build.20231005083309.2171/Python-3.12.0':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
> configure: WARNING: cache variable ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value contains a newline
> configure: WARNING: cache variable ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value contains a newline
> configure: WARNING: cache variable ac_cv_env_LIBS_value contains a newline
> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 4):

For pyenv installed via homebrew on Mac OS, there appears to be a known issue with pyenv failing to build python 3.12.0 due to the incorrect version of openssl from homebrew being used. See [this thread](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2805) for details and suggested workarounds.

One suggested workaround is to first uninstall openssl from homebrew and to re-install it after you've successfully installed python 3.12.0 with pyenv:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
env CONFIGURE_OPTS='--enable-optimizations' pyenv install 3.12.0
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Comment: ...tried this recommendation, but still get the same compiler error.

Comment: This worked on a M2 Mac 

Comment: worked on Intel MacBook Pro

Answer (score 0):

Got the pyenv install to work.  Stumbled about and found a couple local configuration settings were confusing the pyenv build script.